# How to inject javascript into page before page loads with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to inject javascript into a page so that it runs before any other scripts are loaded/executed.

I have searched around and seen multiple suggestions saying that this is possible via the Devtool API and calling `Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument` but I can't seem to get it to work.

This is what I have tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument', {'source': 'alert("This is an alert.")'})
```

The code runs without any error, but no alert is shown in the browser. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should add the code after creating the driver but before you get the web page

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument', {'source': 'alert("This is an alert.")'})
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: This throws an error:
```
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: This is an alert.
Message: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : This is an alert.}
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.107)
```

Comment: works fine for me! try to accept alert in the code the error disapears