# Override JavaScript programatically with python selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

I need to modify a JavaScript that runs on a webpage. The procedure described here [Override Javascript file in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35580017/override-javascript-file-in-chrome) works fine if I set it up manually, however, I would like to set up the override programatically using Selenium (either Geckodriver or Chromedriver) and Python. Is that at all possible? I have the modified JavaScript on my local computer.

Comment: [This](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-execute-a-javascript-using-selenium-in-python#:~:text=Selenium%20executes%20the%20Javascript%20commands,help%20of%20the%20Javascript%20Executor.)?

Comment: Hi Wakeme, I gave it a try but it does not seem to work.The JavaScript on the site continuously handles messages received over a websocket. If I understand the link you send correctly, it allows to execute a JavaScript once, however, I need to handle the messages received over the websocket continously using my modified JavaScript code.

Comment: Like on every event message?

Comment: yes, exactly. It works fine when setting up the overrides manually using the developer tools in Chrome as in this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35580017/override-javascript-file-in-chrome however, I would like to set this up from python

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354352/selenium-how-to-inject-execute-a-javascript-in-to-a-page-before-loading-executi), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68620443/how-to-inject-javascript-into-page-before-page-loads-with-selenium) (See `execute_cdp_cmd`)?

Comment: I tried both, but could not make any of them work, any other suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the extension *Resource Override*, as stated in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35580407/9758790).

To load the extension setting, I tried to

```
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:/Users/USERNAME/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

I am not sure whether there is more elegant way to load the setting of the extension.

FYI: If you want to change the setting of the extensions programmatically, you can refer to this [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50224995/9758790)